# Selecting Rows that are NOT in the Top 5

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using MS-Access, I am trying to select all of the rows that are NOT in the top 5 results of a table. For example, with TableName:

```
Col1|Col2
1   |A
2   |B
3   |C
4   |D
5   |E
6   |F
7   |G
```

I would like to execute the pseudo query:

```
SELECT NOT TOP 5 Col1, Col2 FROM TableName ORDER BY Col1 ASC;
```

with the expected result set of

```
Col1|Col2
6   |F
7   |G
```

Obviously this is not that simple, but I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you define `TOP 5`

Comment: Could it be as simple as a descending sort?

Comment: I edited to add the ORDER BY statement to the query. Unfortunately, a descending sort is not going to work as I do not always know how many rows will be listed outside of these top 5. I just know that anything greater than the first 5 columns will be an issue that need to be addressed. And no, Col1 is not a key or ID number, just representative of the order returned by the record set.

Answer (score 3):

You could do a subquery of the top 5, then a frustrated join to grab all records not in those.  Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM YourTable ORDER BY Whatever
) AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

(I forget offhand if Access allows an order in the subquery, so you may have to save that as a separate query object)

Alternatively, the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 5 FROM YourTable ORDER BY Whatever
)
```

Again though, I'm not sure if Access allows the order by in the subquery, so if you have to save one query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 IDField FROM YourTable ORDER BY Whatever
```

... pretend it's called CriteriaQuery, then reference that query in a different query:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM CriteriaQuery
)
```

(Performance differences over the frustrated join vs where not exists will depend on the data... usually I go with the frustrated join first, for Access, and fine tune if needed)

Comment: Access will give you all matched top 5, which may well be more than 5 results. You can get around this by a sort by whatever and a unique field / column.

Comment: @Fionnuala - good point, I was thinking this was strictly unique ID based, but your point is taken.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NOT IN`

```
select * 
from Table1 as To 
where To.ID not in (
    Select top 5 Ti.id 
    from Table1 as Ti 
    order by Ti.ID)
```

Or `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS [To]
WHERE not  Exists (select * from (Select top 5 *
    from Table1 order by ID )as Ti 
    where To.ID = Ti.ID 
    )
```

However this version of `NOT EXISTS` will not work because the `SELECT` portion of `EXISTS` is ignored so the `TOP` is never processed (took me a while to figure that out)

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS [To]
WHERE not Exists (Select top 5 *
    from Table1 as Ti 
    where To.ID = Ti.ID 
    order by Ti.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.ID NOT IN (

SELECT TOP 5 table.ID FROM table 
ORDER BY table.ID

)
```